# Basic question regarding complexification of a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a real vector bundle over a real manifold $M$. By *complexification* of this bundle we mean the complex vector bundle $E_{\mathbb{C}}$ whose fibers are given by complexifying the corresponding fibers in $E$, i.e. $(E_\mathbb {C})_x = E_x\otimes _{\mathbb {R}}\mathbb{C} \space\space \forall x\in M$.

My question: Is the complexification same as the tensor product bundle of $E$ with the trivial bundle $M\times \mathbb{C}$? Intuitively, I think this is true since the fibers seem to be isomorphic, but not sure how to prove they are isomorphic as bundles over $M$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at transition functions or at local trivialisations.

Comment: @s.harp: I think it works out... is the answer yes?

Comment: So did you get an answer? Are they same?

Comment: @IvinBabu : Yes they are the same, more precisely isomorphic as smooth complex vector bundles. If you consider local trivializations, both of them will have the same transition functions. That is enough to conclude that they are isomorphic.

Comment: @Hajime_Saito Yes, thank you.